# How to avoid old log messages in TailerListener

Tags: java, apache-tailer

I am using the Apache Commons Tailer API to monitor the log files.

Whenever I restart the application, old log messages are also displayed. Instead only new log messages should get displayed.

How do I avoid this behavior of getting the old log messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use the [4-argument `Tailer` constructor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html#Tailer-java.io.File-org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListener-long-boolean-) and pass `true` for the last argument (`end`)? This should make sure that only new lines are returned.

The last argument is documented like this:

> Set to `true` to tail from the end of the file, `false` to tail from the beginning of the file.